# CURL issue in PHP while getting location list

Tags: php, curl, geolocation

I am retrieving the nearest locations available from a given address (Longitude/Latitude) from geolocation website.
It works fine, but for some places it gives junk characters in the name. Moreover, in browser I am getting different characters compared to my PHP CURL functionality.
Here is the URL

http://www.geoplugin.net/extras/nearby.gp?lat=17.7374669&long=83.3214858&limit=5&radius=50&format=php

One of the location is "Sitammapeta" in original location name, but in browser I am getting "Sītammapeta" where as in CURL function I am getting "SÄ«tammapeta".

Please tell me why this difference. I wrote a function to convert browser output to original which works fine.

```
function convert ($old)
    {
        $n="";
        for ($i=0; $i<strlen($old); $i++)
        {
            $n .= chr(ord(substr($old,$i,1)));
        }
        return $n;
    }
```

But I dont understand how I convert the CURL output to original name.

**EDIT**
CURL code

```
$ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'geoPlugin PHP Class v1.0');
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're displaying the data in your web-browser, that the data your sending is UTF-8 encoded and that your browser has no idea about that. If you add `<meta charset="utf-8" />` or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` to the head of your HTML document, that should solve your problem.

**Without the charset defined as UTF-8:**

[image: Without]

**With `<meta charset="utf-8" />` or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`:**

[image: With]

Alternatively, you could have your PHP script send a content-type header using `header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8');` (or replace `text/html` with `text/plain` if you want to use plain text).

**Reference:**

According to [RFC2616 Section 3.7.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html):

> When no explicit charset parameter is
>   provided by the sender, media subtypes
>   of the "text" type are defined to have
>   a default charset value of
>   "ISO-8859-1" when received via HTTP.

That means that if you don't specify a charset, ISO-8859-1 will (should) be used, and as such, some characters won't be displayed properly if the data is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: I need the output in a string, So I cannot use page meta tags. How Can I pass in cURL to set content type

Comment: I tried like this, but it didnt work. $hdrs = array('Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $hdrs);

Comment: @Ajay - Are you outputting the "text" in a web-browser, saving it to a text file or outputting it to a console?

Comment: My requirement is to store in the database as well as printing in the browser for verification

Comment: When displaying "text" in the browser, if you don't specify the charset to use, it will use ISO-8859-1 as mentioned above and therefore UTF-8 encoded characters won't display. Add one of the three options (one of the 2 `meta` options or the `header` one) from above and that will solve the problem. To store the data in your database, make sure the table's encoding is set to UTF-8 and that you specify that it's a UTF-8 connection when connecting (i.e. [`mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)).

Comment: Yes it works, But still I need to convert the characters using my above said function, now I am getting "Sītammapeta" instead of "SÄ«tammapeta", which is better now

Comment: @Ajax - That's great. You see if you can use `iconv` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's just an encoding issue. Whereas your browser can usually automatically detect and employ the best fit encoding, the internals of cURL cannot. I'd look into the [curl_setopt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) function to see what encoding options you can pass.

Comment: please check the response in answer

Comment: I'd make sure to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');` to "zero-out" the accepted encodings and then also explicitly send off a `Content-type: application/json; charset......whatever the charset is...` HTTP header as part of the cURL post.

Comment: I dont understand how to pass exactly for the charset, I checked the Firebug while accessing directly from the browser, It shows  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7, But I dont know how to pass exactly same in CURL

Comment: Look at the example in this user post: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#93686